# Abreviar consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql

En una aplicación, si el usuario inserta un valor en un `input`, la variable llamada `$nro_entrada_registro` va a tomar ese valor y además se va a insertar automáticamente una fecha actual en un campo llamado `fecha_registro`. Pero al actualizar el valor ingresado en el `input` por otro, el campo `fecha_registro` se actualiza también y no quiero eso. Quiero que quede la fecha de la primera vez que se ingresó el dato en el `input` y no se pueda modificar. Si se actualiza el valor que no cambie la fecha. Esta consulta me funciona bien:

```
if ($nro_entrada_registro == '') {

    $sql4 = "UPDATE tramites SET estado_tramite='$estado', 
             nro_entrada_registro='$nro_entrada_registro', 
             fecha_registro=now() WHERE id_tramite='$id_tramite'";

    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql4);

} else {

    $sql4 = "UPDATE tramites SET estado_tramite='$estado', 
             nro_entrada_registro='$nro_entrada_registro' WHERE 
             id_tramite='$id_tramite'";

    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql4);

}
```

Me gustaría saber si hay una forma de poder abreviar este código para que quede solo una consulta hecha? Realizar una especie de `if` como el que hice, pero dentro de una consulta. No sé si es posible.

Answer (score 0):

creo que seria algo asi:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tramites WHERE id_tramite='$id_tramite' AND estado_tramite='$estado' AND nro_entrada_registro='') 
THEN
UPDATE tramites SET estado_tramite='$estado', nro_entrada_registro='$nro_entrada_registro', fecha_registro=now() WHERE id_tramite='$id_tramite' 
ELSE 
UPDATE tramites SET estado_tramite='$estado', nro_entrada_registro='$nro_entrada_registro' WHERE id_tramite='$id_tramite'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql tiene la funcion case

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

podrias hacer algo como

```
SELECT CASE WHEN $nro_entrada_registro='' THEN query1 ELSE query2 END;
```

pero creo que seria mejor que utilizaras un trigger para poner la fecha

```
CREATE TRIGGER put_date AFTER UPDATE ON tramites 
       FOR EACH ROW 
       BEGIN
         IF NEW.nro_entrada_registro = '' THEN  
            UPDATE tramites SET fecha_registro=now()
         END IF;
      END;
```

de esa manera solo tendrías que usar el segundo query y el trigger agregaría la fecha cuando sea necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Pues simplemente puedes reacomodar un poco el código en PHP:

```
$sql4 = "UPDATE tramites SET estado_tramite='$estado', nro_entrada_registro='$nro_entrada_registro'";
if($nro_entrada_registro == '') {
    $sql4 = $sql4 . ", fecha_registro=now() WHERE id_tramite='$id_tramite'";
} else {
    $sql4 = $sql4 . " WHERE id_tramite='$id_tramite'";
}
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql4);
```